Functions maintain the property that sets are measurable
Let $f$ be a function with continuous derivatives on the real axis $\mathbb R$ which satisfies
$\forall x\in\mathbb R\forall y\in\mathbb R(|f(x)-f(y)|\geq m|x-y|)$
where $m > 0$ and is a constant. Prove:
(1) If $E$ is a zero-measurable set, then $f(E)$ is a zero-measurable set
(2) If $E$ is a measurable set, then $f(E)$ is a measurable set
I have tried as much as I can, but I still can't find a way to solve this problem. Feel free to leave your thoughts and answers :)

Are you sure you have the right inequality?

If you mean to say that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq m|x-y|$ for all $x,y$ and some constatn $m>0$, then the result would follow by observing that $f$ is continuous and hence, if $A$ is open, then $f(A)$ is open, and so given that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by all open sets, it must naturally follow that $f(A)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is open. Use the fact that ${A\subset\mathbb{R}:A\text{ open}}$ is a $\pi$-system generating $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ to conclude the proof for every $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

@Daan if $f(x)=|x|$ then $f$ maps $(-1,1)$ which is open to $[0,1)$ which is not open.
